# JavaScript regexp to validate Name with special characters like apostrophe, and spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate names like

```
Dr. D'souza (valid)
Mr. John (valid)
Doe (valid)
```

i.e. allow full stop, space and apostrophe

and inform user when entering invalid special characters like `$ * + ?|\><:;[]{} etc`
I'm new to regexp. tried altering few but couldn't match

```
var errmsg = new Array;
var re = /^[a-zA-Z'.,]+({0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/;

if (!re.test($(this).val())) {
    errmsg.push($(this).attr('placeholder') + ' is invalid');
}
```

Comment: You want the first character to be one of `a-zA-Z'.,`?

Comment: What is `{0,1}` supposed to be modifying? It doesn't make sense to have it right after `(`.

Comment: My own name (Álvaro González) is supposed to not pass your validation?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No sir, a-zA-Z it should start with alphabet only, can contain spaces and '-.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\. |[' ])[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`(?:\. |[' ])` means "either a dot followed by a space, or an apostrophe, or a space". If you need to allow hypens as well for example, replace `[' ]` by `[' -]` (a hypen must be either at the beginning or at the end of a class to be matched). More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Pktx-NtTW6nm16el)

Comment: Remember you need to add a `$` at the end otherwise it will show unexpected behavior for example it accepts strings like abc1 or abc'a1 etc. I did refer to your post but it caused me some trouble because of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z\'\s\.\,]+$/
```

try this regular expression work for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try this one `/^\w(\w|\s|['.])*$/`.